# Git: How do I checkout a branch ignoring all local changes?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

After I have messed around with directories (created/removed) and added/edited both text and binary files, how do I tell git to throw away all my changes, and bring the branch down again, as if I never messed with anything?

Currently I'm doing these two commands.

```
git stash
git stash clear
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

which seems to work. I read in help that -f is used to throw away local changes. If that's the case does ...

```
git checkout <branch> -f
```

do the same thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reset

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: this wasn't working, but after paying more attn to the documentation, it's because the files and dir's weren't being tracked. so first ... git add ., then I could git reset --hard

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard
```

If you want a visual representation of the Branches and commits first type

```
gitk
```

Right-click on the desired previous commit and click on "Reset  branch to here"
You will be presented with 3 options

Use HARD : to discard all the local changes

OR

Use MIXED: to keep the local changed incase if you want to commit again, and it resets the index to the previous commit